# Error using pandas.ExcelWriter.to_excel in python-3.3

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm using Pandas version 0.16.2 and openpyxl version 2.2.4 in python-3.3. I am trying to write a pretty simple pandas dataframe containing floats, strings and NaNs. When I use the code:

```
import pandas as pd
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xls_path)
df.to_excel(writer,'sheet1')
writer.save()
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-3-2349bf9de8ec> in save_xls(list_dfs, xls_path, sheetnames)
      5                  import pandas as pd
      6                  writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xls_path)
----> 7             df.to_excel(writer,sheetnames[n])
      8 
      9     writer.save()

/Users/dylan/Virtualenvs/ve33/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in to_excel(self,     excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, startrow,     startcol, engine, merge_cells, encoding, inf_rep)
   1272         formatted_cells = formatter.get_formatted_cells()
   1273         excel_writer.write_cells(formatted_cells, sheet_name,
-> 1274                                  startrow=startrow, startcol=startcol)
   1275         if need_save:
   1276             excel_writer.save()

/Users/dylan/Virtualenvs/ve33/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py in write_cells(self,     cells, sheet_name, startrow, startcol)
    776 
    777             if style_kwargs:
--> 778                 xcell.style = xcell.style.copy(**style_kwargs)
    779 
    780             if cell.mergestart is not None and cell.mergeend is not None:

/Users/dylan/Virtualenvs/ve33/lib/python3.3/site-packages/openpyxl/compat/__init__.py in     new_func(*args, **kwargs)
     65                 lineno=_code.co_firstlineno + 1
     66             )
---> 67             return obj(*args, **kwargs)
     68         return new_func
     69 

TypeError: copy() got an unexpected keyword argument 'font'
```

Any help on what could be going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a way to reproduce the error? I use Python 3.4, pandas 0.16.2 with excel writer engine `openpyxl`. The following sample code works perfectly on my PC.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 3))

xlsx_path = 'my_excel_file.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(xlsx_path)
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1', engine='openpyxl')
```